# How to add math to your functions for writing to a text file

Tags: python, math, external-data-source

Could someone please help with how the correct way to add math to an already created function that writes output to a text file. The first task was to write the numbers to a output.txt file in values from lowest to highest, no matter the number or how many numbers. This I've done as per my code below. My problem is I now need to show the minimum number on the first line, the maximum number on the second and the average of the numbers on line 3. If anyone could help I would really appreciate the insight

Text file(input.txt)

> min:1,2,3,4,5,6
>
> max:18,25,32,14,15,62
>
> avg:1,2,3,4,5,6

The output should be:

> The min of [1,2,3,4,5,6] is 1
>
> The max of [14,15,18,25,32,62] is 62
>
> The avg of [1,2,3,4,5,6] is 3.4

As mentioned I already have a function to sort the numbers from low to high its just to do the math.

My code so far:

```
def number1():
    inputFile = open("input.txt", 'r')
    lineList = inputFile.readlines()
    fileHandle = open('inputcopy.txt', 'a')
    for line in lineList:
        numbers = [int(item) for item in line.split(':')[1].split(',')]
        numbers.sort()
        fileHandle.write("%s\n" % numbers)  
number1()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the text numbers into `ints` so `python` can process them and map the mathematical operations for example like this:

```py
from statistics import mean


with open('input.txt') as file:
    data = {
        line.split(':')[0]: sorted([int(value) for value in line.split(':')[1].split(',')]) for line in file.readlines()
    }

functions = {'min': min, 'max': max, 'avg': mean}

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(
        f"The {function} of {values} is {functions[function](values)}\n" for function, values in data.items()
    )
```

Which will give you:

```
>>> The min of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] is 1
>>> The max of [14, 15, 18, 25, 32, 62] is 62
>>> The avg of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] is 3.5
```

Comment: Hi Marcos... For some reason im getting a key error: 'i>>¿min'

Comment: @RyCan88 what's the error? I tested it with your sample and generates the correct output, check again your sample file.

Comment: Thanks Marcos! Did you add it just at the end of my current code?

Comment: Hi @RyCan88, no, it does everything, try what I wrote alone.

Comment: Thanks again Marcos I got it to work! but your code doesn't sort the numbers from low to high then write them as shown

Comment: @RyCan88, oh, my bad, i didn't read that part, i updated the answer, it sorts them now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mathematics functions to calculate.

```
import statistics

def number1():
    inputFile = open("input.txt", 'r')
    lineList = inputFile.readlines()
    fileHandle = open('inputcopy.txt', 'a')
    for line in lineList:
        numbers = [int(item) for item in line.split(':')[1].split(',')]
        numbers.sort()
        if line.split(':')[0] == 'min':
             fileHandle.write("%s\n" % min(numbers))
        elif line.split(':')[0] == 'max':
             fileHandle.write("%s\n" % max(numbers))
        elif line.split(':')[0] == "avg":
             fileHandle.write("%s\n" & statistics.mean(numbers))  
number1()
```

Take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/max-min-python/
and https://appdividend.com/2019/01/28/python-statistics-tutorial-mean-function-example/